# SwiftUI pop view upon observable event

Tags: swiftui, combine

I am trying to pop a SwiftUI view upon a particular event from an observed object. How can I do this? This code does not work because I can't refer to `self` inside the `sink` method.

```
struct MyView: View {
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
  @ObservedObject var observable: MyObservable

  init() {
    observable.$state.sink { state in    // !! Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter !!
      presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need publisher here and definitely should not do this in `init` because at least environment is not available there (even you'd solve all others errors).

You just need to observe changes of state in regular way, like below

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Some view here")
        .onChange(of: observable.state) { newState in
            // depending on newState your decision here
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I want. I want to pop in response to an event on my observable.

Comment: It observes same events as you wrote but in correct (in SwiftUI context) way.

Comment: Why is it bound to the text view? And for what purpose is `.sink` used?

Comment: Text there is just for example, you can attach that modifier to any visible view in body. It is in body to have all access to all view context (such things as Environment or EnvrionmentObject is available only there). The `sink` is just another observer, 5-to-1 onChange internally also uses `sink` (or something similar). If you want to work with publisher directly (I don't see here a reason, but...) then you can use instead `.onReceive(observable.$state)` which except first call will do the same. And... instead of verbal arguing give it a try.

Comment: What does this mean "because at least environment is not available there" about `init` function?